# Release App with schedule time in status "Pending Developer Release" after review approved?

Tags: ios, release, review

[image]

I choose a option to manually release app when submit for review. After the app review was approved, I'd like to set a specific time for automatically release.

After all, click the "Save" button is enough or should I click "Release This Version"? Will it release the app immediately ? Which one is correct way?

Comment: in manually you have to release the app and in Automatically app release automatic (whatever time or date you have set before save)

Comment: @seggy You're right!

Answer (score 1):

Let's answer myself.

Yes, You still need to click the "Release This Version" button even you have set a specific release time.

Comment: Are you saying that scheduled releases are not published until you click the `Release` button? Even though you've selected a release date?

Comment: So what's automatic in this "automatic" release if eventually you need to release it MANUALLY?

Comment: @KarloA.López Yes.

Comment: @Tom  I set manually release at first. I think click on "Release This Version" means Apple will release this version with your custom schedule.

Comment: @yonlau Thanks, this solves the case. It's quite confusing to click "Release This Version" while having your release scheduled actually. The button should be             captioned "Release As Scheduled" in such case.